# reading GDAL /vsistdout/ with QProcess on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, stdout, gdal, qprocess

I use GDAL's ogr2ogr to transform large data file.
og2ogr is invoked like so:

ogr2ogr -options  ouputfile  inputfile.

There is also a special output channel /vsistdout/ that will print to the console.

I use QProcess to get the ouput and let the user see the progress of GDAL and to do some more work of mine instead of waiting the end of the process.

```
void myProg::processOutput(){
    qDebug()<< "STD " << process.readAllStandardOutput();
}
void myProg::processError(){
    qDebug() << "ERR " << process.readAllStandardError();
}
    connect (&process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(processOutput()));
    connect (&process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(processError()));
    process.start("C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/ogr2ogr",QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite); 
// in a thread it will not freeze the GUI
    process.waitForFinished();
```

with the above code, no args to og2ogr, it works good and ogr2ogr just answers by giving usage instructions anf failure notice for the missing args and everything is captured by the slot.
But we can see in the debugger window that there has been only ONE output to the slot.

Buffered output problem?

Now if we try a real transformation using the /vsistdout/ like:

```
    process.start("C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/ogr2ogr -f PGDUMP --config PG_USE_COPY YES \"/vsistdout/\" -select code D:/geodata/myshape.shp",QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
    // in a thread it will not freeze the GUI
    process.waitForFinished();
```

but then the output completly vanish like in a black hole althoug it works real nice in a windows console.

Now if I remove de  --config PG_USE_COPY YES   I get the output but in ONE big read when all the work is done. That's NOT what I need!

Is GDAL really writing to /vsistdout/ under Windows or only with Unix?
Is this a QProcess issue or GDAL or Windows?

I tried all advices on this site ans others without any success.
Any advice welcome

PS: I use Qt 4.8 on Windows7

Answer (score 0):

After more trying and searching I finally found a viable workaround.

Ogr2ogr has a switch **-progress** that writes clues to stdout while writing to a file.
      0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

So I changed the starting code to write to a file:

```
 process.start("C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/ogr2ogr -progress -f PGDUMP --config PG_USE_COPY YES \"dump.sql\" -select code bigshape.shp",QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadOnly);
```

This time I get the progress output from GDAL

```
   STD  "0...10"
   STD  ".."
   STD  ".20"
   STD  "."
   STD  ".."
   STD  "30."
```

Now I can let the user see the progress and catch an eventual cancellation signal to abort GDAL.

I cannot process the ouput in real time but it's better than nothing.

about  **-progress** , GDAL doc says:  *Only works if input layers have the “fast feature count” capability.*

God knows who has that capability!